# C++/CLI serial port send command

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a hardware here, wich communicates over serial port. I use MS Visual C++ 2010, and I want to send a command: `<-S->`

I am doing this:

```
SerialPort^ serialPort = gcnew SerialPort(portName , 9600, Parity::None, 8, StopBits::One);
serialPort->Open();
serialPort->WriteLine("<-S->");
serialPort->Close();
```

But the command that goes out is **`<-S->.`**, and not **`<-S->`**
(please notice the point that is attached to the outgoing command).
I use Free Serial Port Monitor to watch my ingoing/outcoming data.

So how can I get rid of that point in **`<-S->.`** ?

This is what is going out:

> 3C 2D 53 2D 3E 0A                     = <-S->.

This is what I want:

> 3C 2D 53 2D 3E                        = <-S->

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is that really a `.` or it's the ending `\0` that FSM displays as a `.`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [`WriteLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline.aspx), which is appending a newline (character 0x0A) to your output (which something is showing as a `.`, but it's not really a dot). Try [`Write()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8.aspx) instead.

Comment: Oh yeah, thats it. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

It is the value of the SerialPort.NewLine property.  A line-feed by default.  Use Write() instead.

There's more trouble, your code will only work well when you single-step with the debugger.  Without it, the Close() method will instantly purge the transmit buffer and only a random number of characters will manage to get sent, including nothing at all.  Only close serial ports when your program terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using C++/CLI, there's really no reason to use the horrid .NET SerialPort class.  The [native Win32 serial port functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363194.aspx) are much more powerful and reliable.  Turn on OVERLAPPED mode, attach an event, and you can get background I/O operations going without having to mess with the thread pool and synchronization.